# Disabling LoopBackRequest in registry to resolve search crawl error

Tags: 2010, crawling, enterprise-search

Can anybody explain why we need to disable the LoopBackRequest in registry to resolve the Search Crawl error.

This article explains about it but I want to know more about it. What is the reason behind disabling LoopBackRequest in registry? How does it impact the Search Crawl error and resolve it.

For reference: http://littletalk.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/access-is-denied-verify-that-either-the-default-content-access-account-has-access-to-this-repository-or-add-a-crawl-rule-to-crawl-this-repository-if-the-repository-being-crawled-is-a-sharepoint-rep/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

harbar.net.... explore his site, it's worth the time.
[DisableLoopbackCheck & SharePoint: What every admin and developer should know.](http://www.harbar.net/archive/2009/07/02/disableloopbackcheck-amp-sharepoint-what-every-admin-and-developer-should-know.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The **loopback check** is a security feature introduced ages ago (server 2003 sp1) and prevents applications to access ressources hosted on the same system via the full qualified domain name. E.g. this happens if you work in your development environment and create a webpart that accesses a webservice hosted on the same box (a loopback).

Above applies for a crawler accessing the SharePoint webservice hosted on the same box.

The KB article with more details is here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926642/en